403 after changing CloudFront distribution from OAC to S3 website endpoint
I have a simple website being distributed with CloudFront. I was using OAC and everything was working great.
When checking my distribution on the console, AWS suggests me the following:

This S3 bucket has static web hosting enabled. If you plan to use this
distribution as a website, we recommend using the S3 website endpoint
rather than the bucket endpoint.

So I changed it to S3 website endpoint and now I am getting 403. I checked the bucket policy and the CloudFront distribution has GetObject access.
So I wonder what could be incorrect in this setup.

S3 website endpoint requires public access
